# Linkedin API PHP - get updates

Tags: api, linkedin-api, updates

After changes (in May) in the LinkedIn API (as discussed here: https://developer.linkedin.com/support/developer-program-transition) I can't retrieve posts/updates (previously done this by: / people/XXX/network/updates) and now I get: 403 error "Access is denied network.".

It is no longer possible get posts/updates?